# How do I automatically 'Pan' popup to fit the View in arcgis JSAPI

Tags: javascript, popup, arcgis-js-api

my popups are being cutoff/out of the view, in an ArcGIS JSAPI build.(4.26x)

I have no trouble using "view.popup.alignment" or "view.popup.dockEnabled" to control the popup location, but those options aren't ideal, and I would like to have the view shift or pan automatically to fit the poupup fully in the map view.

these examples show the shift im looking for-

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/watch-for-changes/live/index.html

(mapbox example showing the same thing..)

https://www.nps.gov/subjects/geology/geologic-resources-inventory-products.htm

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what you're asking for, but you can center the map where you clicked using
`view.goTo(event.mapPoint);`

See [codepen example](https://codepen.io/bsvensson/pen/KKEQoXL?editors=1000).

Comment: Thanks,  goTo is always a nice option,  but the 'popups' need to stay attached to the object selected.   but this could be another direction with some fidgeting,  thx!